# HTML, JS, receiving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when variable has value

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, innerhtml

> Situation

I have a HTML which I would like to display a random word every time it is reloaded.

> Problem

I have the following HTML:

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Oswald', ;">Alex is currently: <span style="color: rgba(25, 114, 120, 1);" id="status">Alive</span></h1>
```

I would like to change the value of `status` to random word other than alive. I have these variables stored in an array and I have a function that runs `onload()`:

```
function changeStatus() {
   let statuses = ['Existing', 'Vibing'];
   let finalStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
   document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = finalStatus;
}
```

> Error

However when I reload my page the following error appears in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

> Ideal outcome

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it, ideally using just Javascript but I can use jQuery if necessary.

Comment: `document.getElementById('user')` should be `document.getElementById('status')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing an id `user` that does not exist. Probably you wanted to have

`document.GetElementById('status')`

Answer (score 2):

There is no element with id 'user'.

Replace

```
document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = finalStatus;
```

With

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = finalStatus;

Answer (score 2):

```js
function changeStatus() {
   let statuses = ['Existing', 'Vibing'];
   let finalStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = finalStatus;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-family: 'Oswald', ;">Alex is currently: <span style="color: rgba(25, 114, 120, 1);" id="status">Alive</span></h1>

<button onclick="changeStatus()">Change Status</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

change `user` to `status`

```
function changeStatus() {
   let statuses = ['Existing', 'Vibing'];
   let finalStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = finalStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get status element, you need to use id which is 'status' not user

var _ele= document.getElementById('status');

_ele.innerHTML = finalStatus;